# How to create through id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a post through the blog id.
Blog has_many posts.

For example: localhost:3000/blog/new_post/1

Number 1 is the blog id. 
And in my create action I assign the id in blog_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pass blog_id in params and write this in your controller.

```
@blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
@post = @blog.posts.create(pass_your_params_here)
```